Give two maximal ideals of a $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ s.t. the two quotient rings are not isomorphic.
A quick note on notation, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the polynomial ring, and $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field of two elements.
I had an exam and one of the questions was:
We say an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is maximal if for any idal $J$ with $I \subseteq J \subseteq R$ we have $I = J$ or $J = R$. Give two maximal ideals $I_1, I_2$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I_1$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I_2$ are not isomorphic.
My answer was marked as incorrect but I can't see why. It goes as follows, with the marker's cross shown as X, presumably to show where I went wrong:
Consider $I_1 = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $I_2 = \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are both countable, they are isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ X, so we have that $I_1 = I_2$. $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I_2$ is simply $\mathbb{F}_2$ X, since all non-zero polynomials can be divided by themselves, giving 1. $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I_1$ will have equivalence classes of 'has same remainder'. Clearly, it's a lot bigger than $\mathbb{F}_2$, and thus $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I_1$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I_2$ are NOT isomorphic.
Now, this isn't as rigorous as could be, but I wrote it in an exam under time pressure. The first X seems to suggest that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic (and thus $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are not both maximal ideals), but I really don't see why. The other X seems to claim that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not equal to $\mathbb{F}_2$, but surely it is since every member of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ can be divided without remainder by itself, except $0$.
I would appreciate any pointer as to where I went wrong, thanks!

Typically the definition of maximal ideal also requires that $I\ne R$, so $\Bbb Q[x]$ should not be a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Q[x]$. Either way, $\Bbb Z[x]$ is not an ideal of $\Bbb Q[x]$, because $1\in\Bbb Z[x]$ but $\frac12\cdot1\notin \Bbb Z[x]$.

BTW, the simplest answer is $I_1=\langle x \rangle$ and  $I_2=\langle x^2-2 \rangle$. The quotient fields are easily shown to be not isomorphic because they have different degrees over $\mathbb Q$. Using  $I_1=\langle x^2-3 \rangle$ also works but proving that the quotient fields are not isomorphic requires some work.

When you say that two objects are isomorphic you need to specify under what structure.
$\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are certainly isomorphic as sets (they are all countable) but not under their natural structures: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain but not a field, $\mathbb{N}$ is not even a ring.
Also, the definition of maximal ideal ${\frak{m}}\subset R$ includes the fact that ${\frak{m}}\neq R$ (else, maximal ideals would be utterly uninteresting).
Also $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is properly included in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ (and it is not an ideal) and the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[X]/\mathbb{Q}[X]$ consists of just one element as $\bar0=\bar1$ whereas $\mathbb{F}_2$ has two elements.

I see, that makes sense. I did find that definition very weird in the exam. I'll retry the question and see if I can come up with another two ideals which work, thanks!

@ettolrach It's important to note that the two sets you described are not both ideals. $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.
